# How do I get the real Web template name and Id from a web?

Tags: 2013, web-template

I'm creating a tool that will "clone" webs inside a site. It reads child webs of a set web and displays them as templates for the user to select from. I've however run into a problem when I try to create new webs using the template name and id gotten from the existing webs.

I'm using the following code to get the template name (of the form: STS#0):

```
//web is an SPWeb instance
var templateName = web.WebTemplate + "#" + web.WebTemplateId;
```

I've created three "template" webs using the standard sharepoint tool:

```
+--------------+-------------------------+------------------+
|     Type     | SharePoint TemplateName | My TemplateName  |
+--------------+-------------------------+------------------+
| Team Site    | STS#0                   | STS#1            |
| Blog         | BLOG#0                  | BLOG#9           |
| Project Site | PROJECTSITE#0           | PROJECTSITE#6115 |
+--------------+-------------------------+------------------+
```

The SharePoint template name is what I've gotten from the available templates list using this code (PowerShell or LINQPad):

```
Get-SPWebTemplate -CompatibilityLevel 15 |? {$_.LocaleId -eq 1033}

web.GetAvailableWebTemplates(1033).Cast<SPWebTemplate>().Select(template => new {Name = template.Name, Title = template.Title}).Dump(1);
```

Shows that the template names i get correspond to thesse:

```
+------------------+---------------+
|       Type       |  What is it   |
+------------------+---------------+
| STS#1            | Blank Site    |
| BLOG#9           | Doesn't exist |
| PROJECTSITE#6115 | Doesn't exist |
+------------------+---------------+
```

What is going on and how can I get the correct template names (name#id form)?

Comment: How did you create you custom web template?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems I've been incorrectly using WebTemplateId where I should be using the Configuration property.

```
//web is an SPWeb instance
var templateName = web.WebTemplate + "#" + web.Configuration;
```

Using this code gives me the correct templateName I can use to create new webs.

Answer (score 0):

## Find the template name of SharePoint site using PowerShell

```
$web = Get-SPweb http://SiteUrl 
Write-host “Web Template:” $web.WebTemplate ” | Web Template ID:” $web.WebTemplateId 
$web.Dispose()
```

## To get a list of all web templates, use the following PowerShell code

```
function Get-SPWebTemplateWithId 
{ 
     $templates = Get-SPWebTemplate | Sort-Object "Name" 
     $templates | ForEach-Object 
     {
         $templateValues = @
         { 
             "Title" = $_.Title 
             "Name" = $_.Name 
             "ID" = $_.ID 
             "Custom" = $_.Custom 
             "LocaleId" = $_.LocaleId 
         }

         New-Object PSObject -Property $templateValues | Select @("Name","Title","LocaleId","Custom","ID") 
     } 
 }

Get-SPWebTemplateWithId | Format-Table
```

Reference: [Get a list of web templates and IDs in a SharePoint site](http://blogs.technet.com/b/praveenh/archive/2013/04/04/get-a-list-of-web-templates-and-ids-in-a-sharepoint-site.aspx)

Comment: As I wrote above this is the code I'm already using, but it doesn't give med the correct template names.

Comment: @Thomas Blog#9 and Projectsite#6115 are custom templates that probably don't have a name specified. See [reference on OOTB templates](http://www.funwithsharepoint.com/sharepoint-2013-site-templates-codes-for-powershell/)

Comment: This is a straight OOTB sharepoint installation. I have not deployed any custom templates at all. If I look at webtemp.xml in 15/templates/1033/xml I can find <Template Name="BLOG" ID="9"><Configuration ID="0" ... So it is available though not returned through Get-SPWebTemplates.